# Less with maven - how to import generated css

Tags: css, maven, less, freemarker

I have a problem with less and maven. I have my less file, generate css from it using maven plugin and I want to use this css file in my views. I have of course this file in target directory (where maven less plugin generate css). 
How correctly import this generated css to my views? Should I use directly path to target resources? Because when I try to import less file for example in this way:

```
<link href="resources/css/variables.less" rel="stylesheet/less"  type="text/css" />
```

less file is imported directly and I got an error that system cannot recognize some variables (which is obvious).
How to do this in correct way? I cannot find any similar problems on internet.

Comment: You should be linking to the compiled css files. I don't use maven so don't know where or how these are compiled though.

Comment: There are in generated 'target' directory. I can do this but I thought that this is something bad and I can do that in more elegant way.